# shell script for i in `ls *` hangs

Tags: shell, for-loop

One of out nightly processes has started hanging.  It only happens about once a week so it's difficult to trace the issue but I have narrowed it down do a for loop.  Even simplifying what it does to just echo the files doesn't work.  The following causes it to hang:

```
for i in `ls *`;do echo $i;done
```

Whereas the following works fine:

```
for i in *;do echo $i;done
```

This is part of our core processes and although I can just remove the `ls` from the loop I would like to know why this change works, especially as this bit of code has been there for years without any issue.  There are not a huge number of files.  Last night there were only 9109 but could this be above some limit for `ls` in a loop?  `ls` on its own works fine too!

Comment: It doesn't answer your question (and hopefully I'm preaching to the converted) but there is absolutely no reason to be using `ls *` over `*`, so you should definitely remove it in any case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ls *` lists the contents of any *sub-directories* as well as files in the current directory. You probably just want `ls` rather than `ls *`, or even just `*`, as the `ls` is somewhat redundant and you've found that this works.

You should also add quoting for file names in case they contain spaces or other special characters, e.g.

```
for i in *;do echo "$i";done
```

Comment: It's not a case of _probably_, looping over the glob as you have shown is the correct way. Good point about the subdirectories.

Comment: @TomFenech: true - "probably" deleted from answer now. ;-)

Comment: While I accept `ls *` isn't a good way of coding this and does need to change it doesn't answer why it's breaking at the moment.  There are no subdirectories in the current directory so files in another location shouldn't be affecting this.

Comment: You probably need to provide more details then. Are there any spaces or special characters in file names ? Are you sure there are no hidden sub-directories (names starting with `.`, e.g. `.git`) ? Is the directory on a server ? What operating system are you using ?

Comment: There are 9109 files in the directory and no subdirectories.  All files are in exacyly the same format - xxxxxx_nnnnnnnn_nnnnnn.dat where x are letters and n are numbers.  There are no subdirectories (even hidden ones).

Comment: Are the file names all the same length ? Your example has 26 characters, and (26+1)*9109 is getting close to the 256k limit which is quite common for command line length. If some of the file names are actually longer than this then you may be hitting this limit. Try `sysctl kern.argmax` or `getconf ARG_MAX` to see what the limit is on your particular system.

Comment: That's it, the character part at the start can vary in length.  The longest complete file name I could find was 35 characters pushing me over the 256K limit.  Does this mean the limit doesn't apply in `for i in *` becasue that command works?

Comment: I have to admit I don't fully understand why the glob expansion does not hit the 256k limit whereas `ls` does. Note that you'd normally use `xargs` for processing large command lines like this, so that you avoid any such limits.